# How to display data to frontend from backend in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display some data in the frontend after getting some data from the backend. The request response in the backend is all god but when it comes to displaying it in the UI is not working. Also using devtools i see that i send the objects insead of one.
I also watched the structure of the object I get and all the necessary properties are there. And I don't know why for some reason I get the 3 objects. the objects are based on the MenuContainer component and it gives me the former selected component and 2 of the actual selected component.
The ItemCardComponent is where I need to display the data. It always goes in the second condition where it says that no data is found but the backend and using console logs i get the data I need but I can't display it. Suggestions ?

Here is the full code:

````
> const Discover = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [type, setType] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [mainData, setMainData] = useState([]);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState(null);
  const BackendUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8000";
  const [placesData, setPlacesData] = useState([]);

  const getPlaces = async () => {
    try {
      if (coordinates && type) {
        const { latitude, longitude } = coordinates;
        const url = `${BackendUrl}/?type=${type}&latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}&lang=${"eu"}`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
          return data; // Return the data
        } else {
          console.error(data);
          return []; // Return an empty array in case of error
        }
      }
      return []; // Return an empty array if coordinates or type are not set
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return []; // Return an empty array in case of an error
    }
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await getPlaces();
    setPlacesData(data); // Set placesData with the received data
    setMainData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [coordinates, type]);

  console.log("ss", placesData);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 bg-white relative">
      <View className="flex-row flex-2 items-center justify-between mt-8">
        <View className="flex-1 flex-row items-center">
          <Image
            source={Venice}
            className="w-full h-[200px] rounded-br-[65px]"
          />
        </View>
      </View>

      <View className="flex-row items-center bg-white mx-4 rounded-xl py-1 px-4 shadow-lg mt-4">
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{ fields: "geometry" }}
          placeholder="Search destination..."
          fetchDetails={true}
          onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            const { lat, lng } = details?.geometry?.location;
            console.log("Latitude:", lat);
            console.log("Longitude:", lng);
            setCoordinates({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng });
          }}
          query={{
            key: "AIzaSyDO5_8WqGXCoStWwkqv8JGlZuQRDIfL1h8",
            language: "en",
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <ScrollView>
        <View className="flex-row items-center justify-between px-3 mt-8">
          <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <MenuContainer
              key={"hotels"}
              title="Hotels"
              imageSrc={Hotels}
              selected={type === "hotels"}
              setType={() => setType("hotels")} // Update the type directly
            />
            <MenuContainer
              key={"attractions"}
              title="Attractions"
              imageSrc={Attractions}
              selected={type === "attractions"}
              setType={() => setType("attractions")} // Update the type directly
            />
            <MenuContainer
              key={"restaurants"}
              title="Restaurants"
              imageSrc={Restaurant}
              selected={type === "restaurants"}
              setType={() => setType("restaurants")} // Update the type directly
            />
            <MenuContainer
              key={"beach"}
              title="Beach"
              imageSrc={Beach}
              type={type}
              setType={setType}
            />
            <MenuContainer
              key={"food"}
              title="food"
              imageSrc={Restaurants}
              type={type}
              setType={setType}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View className="flex-wrap px-4 mt-2">
        {placesData && placesData.length > 0 ? (
          <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            {placesData.map((item) => (
              <ItemCardContainer
                key={item.location_id}
                imageSrc={
                  item?.photo?.images?.medium?.url ||
                  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/30/12/22/eat-1014025_1280.jpg"
                }
                title={item?.name}
                location={item?.location_string}
                data={item}
              />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        ) : (
          <View className="w-full h-[200px] items-center space-y-8 justify-center">
            <Image source={NotFound} className="w-10 h-10 object-cover" />
            <Text className="text-2xl text-[#428288] font-semibold">
              Oops... No Data Found
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}; ```
````